# Where or how can I get something to enhance my audio, choose from more presets, adjust them, etc, for a beginner?

Tags: windows-vista, audio

I listen to an extensive music library through WMP on Vista. I hate WMP's pathetic graphic equalizer. Where or how can I get something to enhance my audio, choose from more presets, adjust them, etc, for a beginner?

Comment: Attempting to "enhance audio" is a beginner mistake by itself. Focus on augmenting what's already there and adjusting for deficiencies, rather than trying to magically "make it better".

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use [foobar2k](http://www.foobar2000.org/). Its fairly simple, and plays music perfectly well. It has a graphic equaliser, but the real power in it in its [addons](http://www.foobar2000.org/components) - which includes an o[ptional graphical equaliser](http://www.foobar2000.org/components/view/foo_dsp_xgeq) and various effects plugins.

Comment: +1 for suggesting the most enhanced audio player on earth to a beginner :D. Don't get me wrong, I'm using foobar incl. self-written scripts for years (I love this piece of software). But so sad that it is foobar is not designed for *beginners*.

Comment: Funny thing, I've been using it for ages sans components, and found it simple, and it worked *exactly* as I expected it to. Most of the components I use are behind the scenes (WSAPI, and at one point ASIO). Its VERY customisable, but its been getting easier with time, especially with the component manager.

Comment: Agree. And I don't want to frighten the OP. Give foobar a chance and you will see: if fb2k can't do it, nobody can do it then.

Comment: They actually have a lighter simpler version now called [boom](http://perkele.cc/software/boom) by the same developer. Just dosen't suit what the OP asked for